# Azure Database for PostgreSQL and Event Triggers

Tags: postgresql, trigger, azure

I am using [Microsoft Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/postgresql/) with PostgreSQL 10 installed. As I'm trying to work on future tables together with other users I want to enable the other users to alter my tables as well.

I've created a role pgpublish and all users are members of the role. For a new table, which I created, I altered the table owner to the role *pgpublish*. Now everyone with the role *pgpublish* is able to alter the table:

```
ALTER TABLE "MYcoolSchema"."CoolNewTable" OWNER TO pgpublish;
```

To make this more automatic/generic, I created a trigger function and tried to create an event trigger [as explained here](https://blog.hagander.net/setting-owner-at-create-table-237/).

Unfortunately I can't create the event trigger (The trigger function works fine), as it is stated:

```
ERROR: permission denied to create event trigger
"trg_create_set_owner" HINT: Must be superuser to create an event trigger. 
SQL state: 42501
```

Is there a workaround for creating event triggers on Microsoft Azure Database for PostgreSQL? How can this look like?

I could run a cron job on another system to scan for new tables and alter the owner of these new tables to pgpublish but this is not cool at all.

Comment: It seems like I need to use runbooks and azure automation to do the work on a scheduled basis...